# Dimple.js change axis units format

Tags: javascript, dimple.js

I have charts using dimple.js to show frequencies of objects. Some of them are thousands of objects and instead of showing 20,000 it shows 20k. This is no good for me at all, is it possible to change the format? I haven't been able to figure out how.

This is my chart

```
drawthis=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(frequencies));
var chartsize=frequencies.length*drawxsize;
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", chartsize, 400);
var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, drawthis);
myChart.setBounds(60, 30, chartsize-50 , 330)
var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", ["Code","Id"]);
myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "freq");
myChart.addSeries("expId", dimple.plot.bar);
myChart.addLegend(65, 10, 510, 20, "right");
x.addOrderRule(draworder,drawdesc);
myChart.draw();
```

This is an example of how it looks

[image]

Thank you all

Comment: By any chance can you make fiddle or plunker demo for us?

Comment: @MahmutKilic I added a picture.

Comment: my answer should solve your problem, please give try and let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make this changes, I believe it should solve your problem

```
var y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "freq");

y.tickFormat = ',.1f';
```

`',.1f` gives you one decimal, if you do not want any decimal just to `',.0f'`

Comment: That was it! Thank you. Dimple is really nice but there is very little documentation and I never found this in the examples. Thanks!

Comment: No problem,  Just to let you know dimple is power by https://d3js.org/ because of that you have extensive tools in d3js that you can use in your dimple, `tickFormat` is one of them. Feel free to post any of your question. Good luck